# Monitoring QKD system with EDR Wazuh

Tags: monitoring, quantum-computing

I’m trying to do my thesis project about the possibility to prevent attacks against QKD devices, using an EDR like Wazuh. The problem is that most attacks are prevented through physical methods applied in the quantum channel. Is there someone that knows an attack against QKD system that could be prevented with an EDR and not using any physical method?

Or maybe some motivations that could justify the monitoring of a QKD device using an EDR?